# Why if JavaScript array.split(' ').push('something') returns number, but not array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Why `obj.className = obj.className.split(' ').push(cls)` - writes number in obj.className, but not array?

I have code:

```
var obj = {
                className: "math lol"
          }

function addClass(obj, cls){
    if(!(cls in obj.className.split(' ')))
        obj.className = obj.className.split(' ').push(cls);
}

addClass(obj, 'PH');
alert(obj.className);
```

Why `alert(obj.className)` display `3`, and don't display array `['math', 'lol', 'PH']`?

Comment: Voting to close: [RTFM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push#Returns)

Comment: push returns the new length of the array after the object is added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Push returns the number of items in the collection, not the collection itself.

Try:

`var currentItems = obj.className.split(' ');
currentItems.push(cls);
obj.className = currentItems`

Instead of:
`obj.className = obj.className.split(' ').push(cls);`

Comment: It might be beneficial to format your code as and `.join` explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript 'push()' method returns the length of the new array. That's why when you assign  obj.className it's value becomes 3. In order to fix it, do this:

```
var obj = {
                className: "math lol"
          }

function addClass(obj, cls){
    alert(obj.className.split(' '));
    if(!(cls in obj.className.split(' '))) {
        obj.className = obj.className.split(' '); //first splitting (NOT ASSIGNING THE LENGTH)
        obj.className.push(cls);  //then pushing
    }
}

addClass(obj, 'PH');
alert(obj.className);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/d56c0wo6/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
obj.className = obj.className.split(' ');
obj.className.push(cls);
```

Instead of:

```
obj.className = obj.className.split(' ').push(cls);
```

`.push()` returns the number of elements and affects the object.

In the future, try splitting your code into smaller pieces while troubleshooting, as such:

```
console.log(obj);
console.log(obj.className)
console.log(obj.className.split(' '));
console.log(obj.className.split(' ').push(cls));
```

Which clearly shows where the problem was in that cascade.

Answer (score 0):

Along with not assigning the result of an array push to get back the array (which, as others have pointed out, returns the number of values in the array after the push), you also don't want to use `in` to determine whether the value you want to check is already in the array. You typically use `in` to check for the existence of a property on an object, but if you're going to use it with an array, then you would use it to check if a value is at a given index:

```
var list = ['AB', 'BC', 'CD'];
if (2 in list) {
  // if there is a value at index 2 of list, then this evaluates
}
```

Instead, you can use indexOf on the string that you already have:

```
if (obj.className.indexOf(cls) === -1) {
  obj.className += ' ' + cls;
}
```

You can also use indexOf to check for a value in an array, but your support matrix is modern browsers (no IE8 unless you polyfill it.) By using `in` to check, your conditional will always evaluate to true (because you're negating something that will always be false) and you will always add the class regardless of whether it was already present.

Answer (score -4):

**in javascript arrays you have to use**

```
console.log(obj.className);
```

**print an array**

Comment: This doesn't help. You will still see that obj.className is an int because of the return type of push(). See my answer below.