# Why does this return a number?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

Why does this code print out `4` rather than `['B', 'e', 'e', 'a']`?

```
var word = 'Bee';
var letters = word.split('').push('a');

console.log(letters);
// -> 4
```

Comment: push returns the length of the array!

Comment: Do `split` and assign to an `Array`. Then do `push` on that `Array`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why if JavaScript array.split(' ').push('something') returns number, but not array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25616978/why-if-javascript-array-split-pushsomething-returns-number-but-not-arr)

Answer (score 3):

As stated here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

> The push() method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and **returns the new length of the array**.

So that is why `letters` assigned as a `Number` rather than the array.

Answer (score 0):

4 is the length of the new array, since you're pushing an element onto a list of characters.

Answer (score -2):

Run

```js
var word = 'Bee';
var letters = word.split('');
letters.push('a');
console.log(letters);
```

Comment: How is this an answer to a “why”-question?

Comment: Why already answered before. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push